# Keep NSArray original order in NSCountedSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nscountedset

I have an `NSArray` and I need to get data from two keys and put together in a `NSMutableDictionary`. One key has `string`values and the other `NSNumber`values. When I try to create `NSCountedSet`without adding the keys I want to use to separate `arrays`, it doesn't work, because the objects are not identical, basically, I need to check if `objectId` is identical, don't matter if the other keys are different.

Here is the initial code:

```
for (PFObject *objeto in objects) {
        PFObject *exercicio = objeto[@"exercicio"];
        NSString *string = exercicio.objectId;
        NSNumber *nota = objeto[@"nota"];
        [exercicios addObject:string];
        [notas addObject:nota];
```

So I create two `NSMutableArrays`and store the values I need. When I `log`the arrays after this, they are perfectly ordered, meaning the `NSString`is in the same `index`of the `NSNumber`it belongs to in the other `array`. So far, so good.

Now, when I create the `NSCountedSet`with the strings, it changes the order.

`NSCountedSet *countedExercicios = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:exercicios];`.

My goal is to `sum` the `NSNumbers` pertaining to an specific object, therefore, when the order changes, I lose the connection between the two `arrays`.

I'm not sure what I could do to solve this problem, or even if there's a different approach to achieve the result I need.

Comment: An NSSet and hence a counted set, does not have an order associated with its elements. NSOrderedSet does, but it is not counted, and not a subclass of NSSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create NSDictionary and add it to array. You will have just one array and you won't lose the connection, you can use objectId as a key and NSNumber as a value:

```
for (PFObject *objeto in objects) {
        PFObject *exercicio = objeto[@"exercicio"];
        NSString *string = exercicio.objectId;
        NSNumber *nota = objeto[@"nota"];
        NSDictionary *dict = @{string: nota};
        [newArray addObject: dict];
}
```

When you need get all key (objectId) you can use NSPredictate.

Hope this help

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. And how would I count the duplicates and sum their values after this? Thanks.

Comment: To get duplicates you have to enumerate the array and compare dictionaries, if you find the duplicate do what you want to do with it. If you want to get sum for, lets say object where objectId is equal 1, you can call NSNumber *sum = [newArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.1"];